# Spring Boot Webapp cannot connect to MariaDb

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, mariadb

1. OS: Windows 10
2. pom.xml configs:
   Spring Boot: 2.0.8
   mariadb: 1.5.9
   flywaydb: 4.2.0
3. Mariadb: 10.2.26

Description: 
My Spring Boot webapp cannot connect to the Mariadb
I have configured root user with pwd on MariaDb and created a db (test)

I get following exception in the Spring Boot app

```
Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC) for user 'root': Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 28000
Error Code : 1045
Message    : Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
```

1. 'root' user is able to login to the db 'test' using HeidiSQL
2. Through mysql CLI I can log into the Mariadb and also in the 'test' db
3. The Web app is configured through application.properties to use another user to access the jdbc data source pointed to the mariadb database with correct port number.
4. application.properties settings

```
spring.test.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.test.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.test.datasource.username=john
spring.test.datasource.password=Doe1!
```

5. I checked the port number 3306 on my PC and it is listening.
6. Can somebody tell me why the application is trying to log through 'root@localhost'? and not john@localhost?
7. Why root is failing to connect? where should the root password provided in the Application?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the properties you defined aren't getting picked up.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
`spring.datasource.url` not `spring.test.datasource.url`

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest you just need to pass proper passwordCharacterEncoding with your connection string.

Eg: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&passwordCharacterEncoding={The character encoding you have used to set the password}